# How is CRC calculated for kernel API's and also for the module API's that are exposed?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

When we compile kernel with `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS` enabled, there is this file generated called `Module.symvers`.

Its sample content is

```
             0x445532c1  usb_serial_generic_submit_read_urb  drivers/usb/serial/usbserial  EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
             0xc47c22e8  mpt_deregister  drivers/message/fusion/mptbase  EXPORT_SYMBOL
             0xdd76c3a2  sata_pmp_error_handler  drivers/ata/libata  EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
```

How is the CRC generated?

```
   When a symbol table is found in the source, the symbol will be
   expanded to its full definition, where  all  struct's,  unions,
   enums  and  typedefs will be expanded down to their basic part,
   recursively.  This final string will then be used as input to a
   CRC algorithm that will give an integer that will change as
   soon as any of the included definitions changes, for this symbol.

   -http://www.skynet.ie/~mark/pub/symbols.txt
```

I wanted to know,

What if the function definition remains the same, but internally the API might call a function whose definition changes. Will the CRC change then?

Comment: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt